# What is up with limsup ? Is Wikipedia wrong about their smooth non-Analytic argument?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, limsup-and-liminf

In [this article on Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) seems to offer the following argument:

> $|F^{(n)}(x_o)| \geq e^{-\sqrt{n}}n^n + O(q^n) \ $  implies  $ \ \displaystyle \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{|F^{(n)}(x_o)|}{n!} \right)^{1/n} = \infty$

where $q = 2^m$ for some positive integer $m$. My initial thought was the implication followed by comparison since
$$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}n^n + O(q^n)}{n!}\right)^{1/n} = \infty \qquad (\text{false})$$
But, I believe the limit above actually converges. In particular, [this example calculation in wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20(%5B200*2%5E%7B3n%7D%2Be%5E%7B-%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7Dn%5En%5D%2Fn!)%5E(1%2Fn)%20as%20n%20goes%20to%20infinity) and similar calculations show  the $O(q^n)$-type term is irrelevant and the limit of $\left(e^{-\sqrt{n}}n^n/n! \right)^{1/n} \rightarrow e$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Since the limsup matches the limit when it exists we cannot conclude the limsup of $\left(\frac{e^{-\sqrt{n}}n^n + O(q^n)}{n!}\right)^{1/n}$ diverges. Therefore, there is no comparison to be made and I don't see how we are able to say anything about $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{|F^(n)(x_o)|}{n!} \right)^{1/n}$.

> **Question:** is Wikipedia wrong here? Show me the error of my ways please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a mistake in the wikipedia article. The given estimate using the term for $k = n$ only shows
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \:\biggl(\frac{\lvert F^{(n)}(x_0)\rvert}{n!}\biggr)^{\frac{1}{n}} \geqslant e\,.$$

To fix it, replace $\cos (kx)$ with $\cos (k^rx)$ for your favourite $r > 1$ in the definition of $F$.

However, the function $F$ as defined in the wikipedia article is indeed nowhere analytic, as one can see using the term for $k = n^2$ for the estimate. Then we obtain

$$F^{(n)}(x_0) \geqslant e^{-n}n^{2n} - C\cdot q^n$$

and that yields

$$\biggl(\frac{\lvert F^{(n)}(x_0)\rvert}{n!}\biggr)^{\frac{1}{n}} \geqslant n\cdot \bigl(1 + o(1)\bigr)\,.$$

Comment: Perhaps $r=3$ is a good choice. I checked, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+(%5Be%5E%7B-%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7Dn%5E%7B3n%7D%5D%2Fn!)%5E(1%2Fn)+as+n+goes+to+infinity and found the modification of $n^n$ to $n^{3n}$ suffices to make it blow-up. I think the introduction of $r$ as you indicate does not spoil anything else, so, I am cautiously optimistic you have tamed this beast. Many thanks.

Comment: Every $r > 1$ works, the dominant term becomes $e^{-\sqrt{n}}n^{rn}$, and $$\biggl(\frac{n^{rn}}{e^{\sqrt{n}}n!}\biggr)^{1/n} \sim en^{r-1}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I can fix the $r$ for my application, but this freedom is helpful. It means we have a family of such functions parametrized by $r$. Neat.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit that I've been fooled by wikipedia @JamesS.Cook. While their argument is wrong, the function given there works without modification. See my edited answer.

Comment: but how can we set $k=n^2$ since $k$ is supposed to be $2^m$ for some $m$. I guess we can choose $m$ such that $2^m \approxeq n^2$ for the argument?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\lim \inf (...)\geq e$ ?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Since we need $\limsup = +\infty$, we can constrain $n$ to be of the form $2^m$. Alternatively, it suffices to take $n^{1+\varepsilon} \leqslant k \leqslant Cn^2$ for a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ and $C > 0$ to get the stronger $\liminf = +\infty$, and taking the $k$ closest to $n^2$ or the largest $k \leqslant n^2$ suffices for that.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You're right that the estimate shows $\liminf \geqslant e$, but for the Cauchy-Hadamard formula one needs the $\limsup$, so the question is whether or not the estimate shows that the $\limsup$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks again, this was very helpful.